# Spring Integration + file reading message source _ Inbound Channel Adapter + Outbound Gateway

Tags: file, spring-integration, file-move

For File reading message source Inbound Adapter and transformer 
    with annotations is configured as below

```
@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(autoStartup = "false", value = "incomingchannel", poller = @Poller("custompoller"))
    public MessageSource<File> fileReadingMessageSource() {

}

@Transformer(inputChannel = "incomingchannel", outputChannel = "jobLaunchChannel")
    public JobLaunchRequest toRequest(Message<File> message) throws Exception {

}
```

Now I want to change the Transformer to  refer to a reply channel of outbound gateway i.e. which moves the files from one directory to another directory i.e. move the file from incomingchannel  directory to a different directory and the process or transform he file or perform some validations

```
<file:outbound-gateway id="mover" request-channel="incomingchannel" reply-channel="newdirectory" directory="<<path to new directory file to be moved" delete-source-files="true"/>
```

Anyone has converted above XML configuration  to annotation configurations or any ideas?

After annotation configurations I will have to change the transformer input channel to  refer to newdirectory  channel i.e. which is a reply channel of messaging gateway...

Thanks in advance for any help ot suggestions regarding this

--- Update 1 after trying out the snippet provided in link by Artem

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "incomingchannel")
public MessageHandler fileWritingMessageHandler() {
    FileWritingMessageHandler handler = new FileWritingMessageHandler(new File(newdirectorypath));
    handler.setFileExistsMode(FileExistsMode.APPEND);
    handler.setDeleteSourceFiles(true);
    return handler;
}

@MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "incomingchannel", defaultReplyChannel = "newdirectorychannel")
public interface MyGateway {

    void writeToFile(@Header(FileHeaders.FILENAME) String fileName, @Header(FileHeaders.FILENAME) File directory,
            String data);

}
```

But there are two problems encountered

1. Inbound Adapter is trying to poll the directory also as file (Recursive Directory scanner is used) - How to ensure that directory is not polled as a file
2. nested exception is `org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=C`

Comment: Sorry, your problem is not clear. Maybe you have something in XML already as a whole solution so it would be easier for us to understand what is a scope of the problem... The `<file:outbound-gateway` is a `FileWritingMessageHandler` in Java. See in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.0.M4/reference/html/file.html#file-writing

Comment: @ArtemBilan,  yes you are right ,  we already have a solution in xml configuration and as mentioned in above code snippet  <outbound-Gateway configuration  to move the file from incoming directory to another director  and then process in the transformer.

Comment: M-m-m. so you want to place a `FileWritingMessageHandler` in between your `@InboundChannelAdapter` and `JobLaunchRequest @Transformer` ?

Comment: @ArtemBilan,  Yes perfect, i have updated the question with the implementation tried but there are exceptions. Also  the InboundChannel Adapter used the recursive directory scanner,  problem is Directory is also scanned and listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Since it looks like you would like to place the `FileWritingMessageHandler` after `@InboundChannelAdapter` and before `@Transformer`, so this should like:

```
@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(autoStartup = "false", value = "incomingchannel", poller = @Poller("custompoller"))
    public MessageSource<File> fileReadingMessageSource() {

}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "incomingchannel")
public MessageHandler fileWritingMessageHandler() {
    FileWritingMessageHandler handler = new FileWritingMessageHandler(new File(newdirectorypath));
    handler.setFileExistsMode(FileExistsMode.APPEND);
    handler.setDeleteSourceFiles(true);
    handler.setOutputChannelName("jobLaunchTransfromerCannel");
    return handler;
}

@Transformer(inputChannel = "jobLaunchTransfromerCannel", outputChannel = "jobLaunchChannel")
    public JobLaunchRequest toRequest(Message<File> message) throws Exception {

}
```

This way an `@InboundChannelAdapter` sends a File into a `FileWritingMessageHandler` for its logic, which produces a result file for the next in flow `@Transformer` to convert a result file into a `JobLaunchRequest`. And only after that a message is going to be sent to the `jobLaunchChannel` to file a Spring Batch `Job`.

Comment: Bilian,  thanks very much for the valuable suggestion and input.  This is working fine  but now the problem is  i dont have track of original file absolute path, is it something i can add in the header when it is passed on to jobLaunchTransfromerCannel

Comment: I don't think this is correct to think about. `FileWritingMessageHandler` produces for you a new `File` object and you have it in your `toRequest(Message<File> message)` method as a message payload. You don't need any *original* because you have everything in this new `File` object.

Comment: Bilian, It is required because the incoming channel  has sub directories and using recursive directory scanner to poll files in any of the subdirectory,  atleast need to know from what original subdirectory the file was moved to the new directory

Comment: Again would like to thank you for all your inputs and valuable suggestions...

Comment: Well, technically a `FileWritingMessageHandler` doesn't override original header. Please, try to consult message headers in your `toRequest(Message<File> message)` method.

Comment: Bilian,  it is working like  a charm..  I have used this   File originalIncomingFile = (File) message.getHeaders().get(FileHeaders.ORIGINAL_FILE);
  originalIncomingFilePath = originalIncomingFile.getParent();

Comment: Only one problem I am facing now is  with Directory also polled as a file message in Inbound Channel Adapter since I am using Recursive directory scanner,   is there any way to restrict  the  directory polled as a message... earlier RecursiveLeafOnlyDirectoryScanner  is now deprecated and I am using RecursiveDirectoryScanner

Comment: Well, you probably need to `@Filter` them (`file.isDirectory()`) before sending to that `@Transformer`. See here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.0.M4/reference/html/message-routing.html#filter