# Spring Integration + Inbound channel adapter + Recursive directory scanner

Tags: file, directory, spring-integration

Inbound channel adapter is created with a poller to poll files present in root directory and its sub directories

```
e.g.  

RootDir 
|_abc.txt
|_subdirectory1
  |_subdirfile1.doc
```

The problem is inbound channel adapter is  reading  the directory also as message

```
@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(autoStartup = "false", value = "incomingchannel", poller = @Poller("custompoller"))
    public MessageSource<File> fileReadingMessageSource(DirectoryScanner directoryScanner) {

    FileReadingMessageSource sourceReader = new FileReadingMessageSource();
sourceReader.setScanner(directoryScanner);

}

@Bean
    public DirectoryScanner directoryScanner() {
        DirectoryScanner scanner = new RecursiveDirectoryScanner();
        CompositeFileListFilter filter = new CompositeFileListFilter<>(
                Arrays.asList(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<>(), new RegexPatternFileListFilter(regex)));
        scanner.setFilter(filter);
        return scanner;
    }

@Trasnformer(inputChannel="incomingchannel",....
torequest(Mesage<File> message) { 

        message.getPayload()

}
```

Here message.getpayLoad is printing subdirectory1  i.e. directory is also read as a file message

I can handle explicitly as file is directory or not in trasnformer and ignore,  but wanted to know is there any way  it can be filtered in Recursive Directory scanner attached to Inbound Channel adapter ?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is probably related to this SO thread: [Spring Integration + file reading message source _ Inbound Channel Adapter + Outbound Gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61372879/spring-integration-file-reading-message-source-inbound-channel-adapter-out).

You need to think twice if you are OK loosing file tree. It sounded for me that you would like to restore a tree in the `FileWritingMessageHandler`. So, it is probably better to `@Filter` messages with directory payload before sending to that transformer.

If you still want to skip dirs from the producing, consider to use a `ChainFileListFilter` instead of `CompositeFileListFilter` and configure a `RegexPatternFileListFilter` first.
This way a filtered directory from the `RegexPatternFileListFilter` (it is skipped by default see `AbstractDirectoryAwareFileListFilter`) won't go to the `AcceptOnceFileListFilter` at all. In your current configuration the `AcceptOnceFileListFilter` being first accepts a directory and really ignores the next filter in the composition.

**UPDATE**

What I mean should be like this:

```
@Bean
public DirectoryScanner directoryScanner() {
    DirectoryScanner scanner = new RecursiveDirectoryScanner();
    ChainFileListFilter filter = new ChainFileListFilter<>(
            Arrays.asList(new RegexPatternFileListFilter(regex), new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<>()));
    scanner.setFilter(filter);
    return scanner;
}
```

Nothing more. As long as your `regex` is just for files, any sub-directory would be skipped and not allowed to go downstream.

Comment: thanks very much for the input.  I have added chain filter with regex  to exclude the directory,  however this will have a limitation to know the directory name and changes required everytime i add a new subdirectory,   is there any way excluding by extending the Recursive Directory scanner or at message payload level in filewritermessagehandler ?

Comment: Well, let me know first of all that you have read this answer! I didn’t say to apply a regexp for dirs...

Comment: Please, see an UPDATE in my answer.